# How can I delete applications inside /Applications/Systems?

Tags: big-sur

How can I remove applications in `/Applications/Systems`? I have tried `csrutil disable` and then `sudo rm -rf Dictionary.app`(or any app), but still I got the follow response:

```sh
rm: Dictionary.app: Read-only file system
```

How can I safely remove them?

I am using `BigSur 11.2.3`

Comment: Dictionary.app is 2.8 Mb of space. There's very little justification for removing any of the Apple-bundled apps. (I've never used Chess, either.)

Comment: I am just using it as an example. If I learn how to remove it safely, I can try and remove other stuff there that I don't want.

Answer (score 5):

You can't *safely* remove them.

You can't delete any files on the read-only system volume.  That includes all applications installed with macOS with the exception of Safari.

Comment: Technically one can mount the **Macintosh HD** _volume_ in **macOS Big Sur** as _writable_ with the proper steps and delete whatever, however, I strongly advise against doing it.

Comment: @user3439894 which was why I said safely.  But I agree you can do it if it is really really important. So I upvoted your comment.